# Question about API's and Postman and or anyway to retrieve data and populate parameters

Tags: php, api, soap

Not sure if this is possible but here's what i'm trying to accomplish through postman but i'm open to using terminal or anything recommended if it's easier.

I have this xmlSoap file and let's say it resides here: http://test.myapi.local:7947/my/path/here/myWSAPI

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI"
             targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000"
                elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000">
            <complexType name="APIDataCapture">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Code" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty1" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty2" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty3" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Qty4" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="Root" mixed="true">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="APIDataCapture" type="tns:APIDataCapture"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="Root" type="tns:Root"/>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014"
                elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014">
            <complexType name="APIDataCapture">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="0" name="EntryNo" type="int"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderFound" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderNo" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="0" name="SalesOrderLineNo" type="int"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderETADate" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SalesOrderItemNo" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="Root" mixed="true">
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="APIDataCapture" type="tns:APIDataCapture"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="Root" type="tns:Root"/>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MyWSAPI">
            <element name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="itemNo" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="date"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="custNo" type="string"/>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="extDocNo" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="return_value" type="boolean"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_Quantity">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q1="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q1:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q2="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x00000" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q2:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="GetSalesOrderETA">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q3="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q3:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element xmlns:q4="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x50014" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                                 name="aPIDataCapture" type="q4:Root"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_Quantity">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_Quantity"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Get_Item_Quantity_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetSalesOrderETA">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSalesOrderETA"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSalesOrderETA_Result"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="MyWSAPI_Port">
        <operation name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
            <input name="Get_Item_ETA_Date" message="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date"/>
            <output name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result" message="tns:Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
            <input name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No" message="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"/>
            <output name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result" message="tns:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Get_Item_Quantity">
            <input name="Get_Item_Quantity" message="tns:Get_Item_Quantity"/>
            <output name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result" message="tns:Get_Item_Quantity_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetSalesOrderETA">
            <input name="GetSalesOrderETA" message="tns:GetSalesOrderETA"/>
            <output name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result" message="tns:GetSalesOrderETA_Result"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="MyWSAPI_Binding" type="tns:MyWSAPI_Port">
        <binding xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/MyWSAPI:Get_Item_ETA_Date" style="document"/>
            <input name="Get_Item_ETA_Date">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Get_Item_ETA_Date_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No"
                       style="document"/>
            <input name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Find_Duplicate_Ext_Doc_No_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Get_Item_Quantity">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:Get_Item_Quantity" style="document"/>
            <input name="Get_Item_Quantity">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Get_Item_Quantity_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetSalesOrderETA">
            <operation xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                       soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/myWSAPI:GetSalesOrderETA" style="document"/>
            <input name="GetSalesOrderETA">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="GetSalesOrderETA_Result">
                <body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="myWSAPI">
        <port name="myWSAPI_Port" binding="tns:MyWSAPI_Binding">
            <address xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                     location="http://test.myapi.local:7947/my/path/here/myWSAPI"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

I'm trying to make a call to the “Get_Item_Quantity” function in the web service.

Function name: `Get_Item_Quantity`

This function takes `Type`, `Code fields` and returns `Qty1`, `Qty2`, `Qty3`, and `Qty4`
Parameters:

```
Type = 0 – input value
Code = ‘product100317’ – input value
Qty 1 – return value
Qty 2 – return value
Qty 3 – return value
Qty 4 – return value
```

I created a file CustomInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\CustomApi\Api;

interface CustomInterface
{
    /**
     * GET for Qty api
     * @param int $type
     * @param string $code
     * @return string
     */

     public function getQty($type,$code);
}
```

and a file called Custom.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\CustomApi\Model\Api;
    
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    
    class Custom
    {
        protected $logger;
    
        public function __construct(
            LoggerInterface $logger
        )
        {
            $this->logger = $logger;
        }
    
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function getQty($type,$code) {
            $response = ['success' => false];
    
            try {
                // Logic to call soap service here
                $qty = $this->getItemQty($type,$code);
                $response = ['success' => true, 'qty' => $qty];
    
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
                $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
            }
    
            $returnArray = json_encode($response);
            return $returnArray;
        }
    
    
        /**
         * Soap API call 
         *
         * @param int $type
         * @param string $code
         * @return void
         */
        public function getItemQty($type,$code)
        {
            $soapRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
              <soap12:Body>
                <Get_Item_Quantity xmlns="http://test.com/">
                    <Type>' . $type . '</Type>
                    <Code>' . $code . '</Code>
                </Get_Item_Quantity>
              </soap12:Body>
            </soap12:Envelope>';
            $header = array(
                "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                "Accept: text/xml",
            );
            $soapHandler = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test.com/");
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapRequest);
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            curl_setopt($soapHandler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
            //header('Content-type: text/xml');
            $result = curl_exec($soapHandler);
            $qtyData = array();
            if ($result === false) {
                $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soapHandler);
                curl_close($soapHandler);
                $this->logger->info($err);
            } else {
                curl_close($soapHandler);
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
                $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
                $result = $xml->xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body');
                $res = $result[0]->Get_Item_Quantity_Result;
                $qtyData = simplexml_load_string($res);
            }
            return $qtyData;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to add these files into postman and the endpoint link to test if i can populate the parameters? Is there an easier way to do it through command line and curl? I'm open for any avenue. Kind of a newbie to postman and API calls.

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue. What do you mean by _"add these files into postman and the endpoint link"_? Which files?

Comment: Is there a way to add any files into postman? Doesn't matter which, is this a possible feature? @El_Vanja

Comment: Adding files in what sense? To emulate the submission of a file? To use as a source for the request body? Something else?

Comment: yes correct to use as a source for the request body... basically the code above are my files.

Comment: I see no need in doing so. You can, for example, copy your entire XML contents into the body of a Postman request and save it so that you may recall it whenever you need to.

Comment: Why do you want to add PHP files to postman? Using Postman you can test your API by sending requests to it. Postman will indirectly call you PHP files, but there's no need to ADD them to Postman. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for that @RenéPöpperl, honestly i just was not sure how it works... so how do i call my php files. Also, @ El_Vanja, I will save my XML contents into the body of a Postman request. seems like a good way to start. What comes next?

Comment: So i added my xml to the body and i'm trying to hit my api endpoint.

Comment: http://164.90.154.246/index.php/rest/all/V1/custom/custom-api/

Comment: If someone could just layout the proper steps for postman and forumulate and answer i'll accept it. I have put my xml in the body and my endpoint is above which i assume i need to POST. Like i said above i'm trying to see if i can return the values from Get_Item_Quantity with my php code (interface)

Comment: All you need to do with Postman is to form a proper request and send it to the right URL. Now, a "proper" request depends on how you designed your endpoint - it's *you* who defines which method is used (`get`, `post`, etc.) and what type of content is accepted (in your case, XML). Your question boils down to "how do I use Postman", which makes it rather off-topic for Stack Overflow. The Postman [documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) seems like a good place to start.

Comment: Yes and maybe off topic. I've seen more off topic than this question.

Comment: I keep getting the error     "message": "Request does not match any route."